# Upgrading Joytech hub from 8 speed to 10 speed

Tags: drivetrain, upgrades, freehub

I have a Joytech hub and I'm planning to upgrade from 8 to 10 speed. With my Joytech rear hub, do I need to change my hub first and does my hub support 10 cogs?

Comment: There is more than one joytech hub.

Answer (score 1):

Provided the hub has a Shimano/SRAM compatible cassette body you should be able to upgrade to 10 speed with your existing hub.  Campagnolo 8 speed cassette bodies are incompatible with Campy 10 speed cassettes so if you are running Campy you will need a new hub.

Comment: @batman for a given speed... there are no differences in cassette spacing between road and mountain.  The difference is the gear range